# Styling in Ionic 3.x: Ion-Icon with gradient background colour (ion-chip)

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to give an icon a gradient background. How can I do that?

I tried putting the ion-icon into a ion-chip, like this:

```
<ion-chip class="my-chip">
   <ion-icon name="basket></ion-icon>
</ion-chip
```

And then in the .css file:

```
.my-chip{
  color: linear-gradient( 0deg, #color1 0%, #color2 100%) !important;
}
```

But this didn't work. Color one and color two are obviously given in hex code.

Comment: Can you show the final view of your UI component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `background-image`

In your .css file,

```
.my-chip{
  background-image: linear-gradient( 0deg, #color1 0%, #color2 100%) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped! Only difference is, that I had to do this styling into .my-icon. Other than that, this is the right command :)

Comment: This will create a background image, but won't give the color to icon.